# Handling multithreadiing issue in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".getDetails").click(function() {
    // some stuff like fetching response from server
})
```

when user clicks getDetails button on UI multiple times within fraction of second , jquery generates two calls  for click function and my logic fails.
 I think solution to this will be to disable the button on first click itself(so that use can't click multiple times). Once i get the response or just before returning
 from click method i make it enable. Is there any better solution ?

If no, how can i make button disable  as soon as user click button first time. I think it needs to be done before calling click method or some where in html element ?

Java provides synchronized keyword so that only one thread enters at time inside method , i am not sure is similar thing exist in javascript or not ?

Comment: What logic is being performed in the click handler? I assume it's an AJAX request

Comment: Yes. You should disable the button on first click to prevent successive clicks.

Comment: @james agin my question is at what point of time i need to do it and where i need to do it. Can you provide some example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the click handler executes an AJAX request you can set the button as disabled before making the request, then enable it again once the request completes. Try this:

```
$(".getDetails").click(function(){}
    var $btn = $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/foo'
        success: function() {
            console.log('It worked!');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('It failed!');
        }, 
        complete: function() {
            $btn.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But in this case also there is a probability two thread enters at same time inside click method and then both will proceed. Right ?

Comment: JS is only single threaded so that issue is moot. However this would avoid the problem of quick successive clicks firing the the event handler multiple times before the first AJAX request completes.

Comment: Sorry I did not get  what do you mean by JS is single threaded ? Does it mean second thread can not enter the method till first thread completes. If yes i should not have faced the issue. Is n't it ?

Comment: Js only operates on a single thread. It runs on an event based system - this is what caused your issue. One event was still in process while another was raised. That is the problem that this answer solves.

Comment: No, multiple events can run at the same time. You seem a little confused about how threads work. I would suggest researching that - although it's not directly related to JS.

Comment: Does it mean JS will complete first requested event(though internally it will get the request for second event/click). Once first is completed, it will pick the second event ? But in my case if second event would have been picked only after if first  was completed, there should not have been any issue. Can you please elaborate why i am facing this issue if JS is single threaded. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Does it mean JS will complete first requested event(though internally it will get the request for second event/click). Once first is completed, it will pick the second event?` No - again, multiple events can be handled at the same time. Single threaded does not mean that multiple events cannot be processed simultaneously.

Comment: Ok looks like i start getting it now. It means single thread can run process simultaneously at same (may be in round robin fashion). Hope its correct now.
If yes even if i go by your solution approach, say user click button two time within fraction of second before thread js thread executed 
` .. $(this).prop('disabled', true)...  ` inside click method then in that case still JS will continue to process both events ?

Comment: That's correct, but the user would need to click very, very quickly to do that. Probably < 10ms between clicks. Here's an example, https://jsfiddle.net/2omgqav9/. Try it for yourself :)

Comment: Ok Thanks Rory for your patience. Then is there not any full proof solution  that works irrespective the frequency user is clicking the button or this is the approach generally people take for this kind of problem.

Comment: This is the generally accepted approach to solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

*you can try unbinding click event and after ajax call again bind click to that class*

```
$(".getDetails").click(function(){}
$(".getDetails").unbind('click');
 // some stuff like fetching response from server
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple flag to prevent firing your logic multiple times:

```
var flag = true    
$(".getDetails").click(function() {

  if (flag) {
     flag = false;
     //your logic...

     //when your code ends (in after-AJAX callback for example)
     flag = true;
  }

});
```

Comment: But in this case also there is a probability two thread gets the value as true at same time  and both send the request

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry I did not get  the statement `There's no such thing as "two threads" in js`  ?Does it mean second thread can not enter the method till first thread completes. If yes i should not have faced the issue. . Right ?

Comment: No, I meant that javascript is single-threaded.  There is only one thread.  Only one "bit" of javascript can be running at a time - so, yes, your method must exit before it can start again... *except* if you run something that says "run this later", eg `setTimeout` or `$.ajax` (and derivatives)

Comment: @user3198603 I think it might be helpful for you to read some articles about multi-threaded code and asynchronous code in order to know what's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".getDetails").click(function(e){

  var $target = $(e.currentTarget); 
  // assuming the click listener is on the button

  $target.prop('disabled',true);

  // request, stuff...and when done:
  $target.prop('disabled',false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try Prevent Default and return false to avoid any other event propagation
This is solution is like semaphore or monitor

```
var progress = false;
$(".getDetails").on('click', function(e) {
if(!progress){       
progress = true;
// some stuff like fetching response from server
//also  after sucessfull fetch make  true to false again
}else{
   console.log('something in progress'); 
}
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make sure that your button will not fire the async request twice, until you have a response.

```js
function doAjaxReq() {
  /*
    Add your ajax operation here
    as a return value of doAjaxReq
    like so:
    
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/foo',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data
    })
    
    Since i can't use ajax here let's smilulate
    it useing a promise.
  */
  promise = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      res({foo: "bar"});
    }, 1000)
  })
  return promise;
}


/* 
Inside here you add the click handlder
only once use `elem.one('click'...`
*/
function addClickHandler(elem) {
  elem.one('click', function() {
    // do your ajax request and when its
    // done run `addClickHanlder` again
    // i'm using `.then` because of the promise,
    // you should be using `.done`.
    doAjaxReq().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      addClickHandler(elem);
    });
  })
}

addClickHandler($(".getDetails"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="getDetails">Get Details</button>
```